# Is it UB to reinterpret_cast the first union member to the type of the active union member?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Given the code:

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B { std::string s; };

struct C
{
    union
    {
        A a{};
        B b;
    };
};
```

is the following access well defined:

```
void foo()
{
    C c;        // c.a is active
    c.b = {};   // now c.b is active

    auto& b = reinterpret_cast<B&>(c.a); // read c.b via access to c.a
    // use b somehow
}
```

Comment: The specific code in your question is probably legal because of the common initial sequence guarantee in [class.union.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.union). You might want to put something in those structs...

Comment: @dratenik if I read that paragraph correctly, it allows to access `c.a.x` via `c.b.x` (assuming they're layout compatible). So it talks about members of the union members, but I'm asking about the union members themselves.

Comment: I would says that first union-member acts as any other union-member. And I would say that reinterpret_cast inactive union member is pedantically ill-formed or UB.

Comment: @Jarod42 wouldn't that mean that casting via a named union would also be UB, e.g. `auto& b = reinterpret_cast<B&>(c.myUnion)`. Are we accessing an inactive member here? Since pointers between classes and their first member (ignoring type restrictions here) is well defined, I'd assume it's also ok to access it via the first member. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/GoWf7efWa)

Comment: ub or not what you wait from this? nothing you'll catch there

Comment: I would say that `reinterpret_cast<B&>(c.myUnion)` is ok, whereas `reinterpret_cast<B&>(c.myUnion.a)` is not. I normally check UB with `constexpr` function, but unfortunately, `reinterpret_cast` is not `constexpr`. :/

Comment: A union and all its members are pointer-interconvertible, which means reinterpret_cast between their addresses (and references) is well-defined. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#pointer-interconvertible

Comment: You might like to add using (de-referencing) the pointer to the question.  The Standard allows lots of pointer to pointer conversions that do not produce a pointer than can be legally de-referenced.

Comment: @Jarod42 Lifetime of an object doesn't affect interconvertibility.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) in the "Notes" section, it is perfectly legal to reinterpret_cast a pointer to one member of a union to a pointer of the type of another member of the union.

> Assuming that alignment requirements are met, a reinterpret_cast does not change the value of a pointer outside of a few limited cases dealing with pointer-interconvertible objects:

```
struct S1 { int a; } s1;
struct S2 { int a; private: int b; } s2; // not standard-layout
union U { int a; double b; } u = {0};
int arr[2];

int* p1 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&s1); // value of p1 is "pointer to s1.a" because s1.a
                                   // and s1 are pointer-interconvertible

int* p2 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&s2); // value of p2 is unchanged by reinterpret_cast and
                                   // is "pointer to s2". 

int* p3 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&u);  // value of p3 is "pointer to u.a": u.a and u are
                                   // pointer-interconvertible

double* p4 = reinterpret_cast<double*>(p3); // value of p4 is "pointer to u.b": u.a and u.b
                                        // are pointer-interconvertible because both
                                        // are pointer-interconvertible with u

int* p5 = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&arr); // value of p5 is unchanged by reinterpret_cast and
                                    // is "pointer to arr"
```

Comment: `double* p4 = reinterpret_cast<double*>(p3);` dereferencing `p4` will definitely be UB. You can't just reinterpret_cast between any pointer types (technically you can't dereference them, but whatever). Also, while `p4` is in your case kindof _aliasing_ `u.b`, reading it will still be UB because `u.b` is not the active member of the union.

Comment: I know that `cppreference` is not the standard, but it is probably the best free reference without actually reading the standard directly. The example above is a direct copy from the page I linked to. I don't know the validity of this example according to the standard.

Comment: The very sentence following it says _"Performing a class member access that designates a non-static data member or a non-static member function on a glvalue that does not actually designate an object of the appropriate type - such as one obtained through a reinterpret_cast - results in undefined behavior"_. So yes, you can cast them, but you still can't dereference them because of what I said earlier.

Comment: And OP cast from (inactive) union-member, not from the union itself

Comment: According to the quote given above it is valid to reinterpret_cast a pointer to one member in a union to a pointer to another member in the same union, as the address will not change. In the question, a pointer to the active member is dereferenced, so the discussion about dereferencing a pointer to the inactive member is moot.

Comment: The only thing that is not specified in the quote above is the access to `c.a` before doing the `reinterpret_cast`. But technically speaking, there is no access to the value stored in `c.a` only the address of it.